# How to improve the performance of my query which uses select top 20 and a bunch of isnull in the where clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-performance

```
select top 20 id
from Employee e
where e.state=IsNull(@State,e.state)
and   e.industry=IsNull(@Industry,e.Industry)
```

Comment: Are you already using indexes on the Employee table?  If so, what is the index structure/syntax?

Comment: A `top 20` without an explicit `ORDER BY` is moot - since you don't have any ordering - which "top 20" rows do you expect to get??

Comment: you should look at this article. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Comment: YOu shoud read this: http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issue I see here is use if `ISNULL()` function in `WHERE` clause and using parameter in `WHERE` condition which makes it difficult to determine whether to use index seek or not.

Per my observation, you can either change your `WHERE` condition to be like

```
where e.state is null or e.state = @State
and   e.industry is null or e.Industry = @Industry
```

(OR) try using a dynamic query instead like

```
declare @sql varchar(200);
declare @cond varchar(100);

set @sql = 'select top 20 id from Employee e ';
if(@State is not null)
set @cond = @cond + ' and e.state = @State'
if(@Industry is not null)
set @cond = @cond + ' and e.industry = @Industry'

IF len(@cond) > 0
SET @sql = @sql + ' WHERE ' + RIGHT(@cond, LEN(@cond)-3)
```

Dynamic query idea taken from [Here](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/)

Comment: If the parameters are meant to be optionnal I think it should be something like `where (@State is null or e.state = @State) and   (@Industry is null or e.Industry = @Industry`).